# How does a CPU know the size of a variable to correctly read it?

Tags: assembly, size, byte, cpu

Well I'm quite blunt on this type of subject, so sorry if I'm completely out of line on things. I'll try to be clear.

In memory when commands are being read for say, How does the CPU know that it has to e.g. read a 4 byte string or a 10 byte string to work with for that command? or another command, the CPU knows that it has to read the size of an int64 to correctly read the data to work with it? is the size stored somewhere? possibly calculated?

Comment: compiler generates the code which enables proper reading of variables.

Comment: Thanks all - after Googling some time later it all made seanse! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data size is usually encoded in the instruction, or is implicitly known. In for example x87:

```
fild    word [testdata]    ; loads 16 bits

fld     dword [testdata]   ; loads 32 bits
fld     qword [testdata]   ; loads 64 bits
fld     tword [testdata]   ; loads 80 bits
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at strings for a partial answer to this, in C one has to null-terminate one's strings (i.e. end it with a null byte or `\0`) therefore it's a simple job of reading up to the null byte.

On fixed types of data (let's say an `int`) then the compiler will inform the CPU that it's dealing with an int and as both compiler and CPU will be working with the same architecture, their `int`s will be the same length.